# streaming over http from vlc

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, vlc, codec

I want to stream a video over my local network (a wireless router setup),

I followed the steps at http://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/

But the client is not able to open the video file

Giving the error - 
No suitable decoder module:
VLC does not support the audio or video format "undf". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

Even on the same machine, sometimes i get the same error and sometimes it plays

I am not able to understand what am i missing :P

EDIT: I am using a .mp4 file as source, and the generated string is

`:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} :sout-keep`

Comment: What kind of file are you using as input. Please also post the "Generated stream output string" shown by VLC, the thing that starts with `:sout=#transcode ...`

Answer (score 0):

On the `Destination Setup -> Transcoding` page the profile selected by default says `Video - H.264 + MP3 (MP4)`.

Click the **Edit selected profile** button, go to the `Audio codec` tab and change the **Codec** option to either **MP3** or **MPEG 4 Audio (AAC)**.

This should help avoiding the unknown codec error.